# Pasar filas a columnas en mysql

Tags: mysql

¿alguien sabe cómo puedo pasar las filas de una consulta MySql a columnas? he estado buscando y encuentro que se puede utilizar SUM o GROUP_CONCAT pero no entiendo del todo los ejemplos, de antemano muchas gracias.

Logré solucionar ese problema con la ayuda de @Voiser, muchas gracias! :)

Comment: Buenas @Sandra, podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar parte de la query o lo que hayas intentado ?

Comment: Hola Sandra, si te ayudo la respuesta de @Voiser marcala como respuesta aceptada con el boton en forma de V del lado izquierdo de la publicación, asi ayudaras a futuros usuarios con el mismo problema y tu ganaras reputación

Answer (score 4):

te dejo un ejemplo que es lo que buscas, en el ejemplo una tabla productos, se crea el esquema y se hacen unos `insert`:

```
CREATE TABLE products
(
    prod_id INT NOT NULL,
    prod_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (prod_id)
);

INSERT INTO products (prod_id, prod_name)
VALUES (1, 'Shoes'), (2, 'Pants'), (3, 'Shirt');

CREATE TABLE reps
(
  rep_id INT NOT NULL,
  rep_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (rep_id)
);

INSERT INTO reps (rep_id, rep_name)
VALUES (1, 'John'), (2, 'Sally'), (3, 'Joe'), (4, 'Bob');

CREATE TABLE sales
(
  prod_id INT NOT NULL,
  rep_id INT NOT NULL,
  sale_date datetime NOT NULL,
  quantity INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (prod_id, rep_id, sale_date),
  FOREIGN KEY (prod_id) REFERENCES products(prod_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (rep_id) REFERENCES reps(rep_id)
);

INSERT INTO sales (prod_id, rep_id, sale_date, quantity)
VALUES 
  (1, 1, '2013-05-16', 20),
  (1, 1, '2013-06-19', 2),
  (2, 1, '2013-07-03', 5),
  (3, 1, '2013-08-22', 27),
  (3, 2, '2013-06-27', 500),
  (3, 2, '2013-01-07', 150),
  (1, 2, '2013-05-01', 89),
  (2, 2, '2013-02-14', 23),
  (1, 3, '2013-01-29', 19),
  (3, 3, '2013-03-06', 13),
  (2, 3, '2013-04-18', 1),
  (2, 3, '2013-08-03', 78),
  (2, 3, '2013-07-22', 69);
```

Se realiza un `SELECT` vil y vulgar:

```
SELECT 
  r.rep_name,
  p.prod_name,
  s.sale_date,
  s.quantity
FROM reps r
INNER JOIN sales s
  ON r.rep_id = s.rep_id
INNER JOIN products p
  ON s.prod_id = p.prod_id
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Ahora hacer el cambio de fila por columnas:

```
 SELECT 
  r.rep_name,
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.prod_name = 'Shoes' THEN s.quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Shoes,
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.prod_name = 'Pants' THEN s.quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Pants,
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.prod_name = 'Shirt' THEN s.quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Shirt
FROM reps r
INNER JOIN sales s
  ON r.rep_id = s.rep_id
INNER JOIN products p
  ON s.prod_id = p.prod_id
GROUP BY r.rep_name;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para mostrar las repeticiones en cada columna y los productos en las filas:

```
SELECT 
  p.prod_name,
  SUM(CASE WHEN r.rep_name = 'John' THEN s.quantity ELSE 0 END) AS John,
  SUM(CASE WHEN r.rep_name = 'Sally' THEN s.quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Sally,
  SUM(CASE WHEN r.rep_name = 'Joe' THEN s.quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Joe,
  SUM(CASE WHEN r.rep_name = 'Bob' THEN s.quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Bob
FROM products p
INNER JOIN sales s
  ON p.prod_id = s.prod_id
INNER JOIN reps r
  ON s.rep_id = r.rep_id
GROUP BY p.prod_name;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Si deseas probar este ejemplo te dejo un demo : 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Row to column Mysql](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6cc17/35)